# Scala analysis with SonarQube 5.4

Tags: scala, sonarqube, sbt

I want to know if SonarQube 5.4 supports scala? Can we perform scala analysis with respect to SonarQube? By default SonarQube does java analysis, I want to know if it works with scala because our code is built with sbt.

I've gone through some third party plugins like

- Sagacify/sonar-scala
- ncredinburgh/sonar-scalastyle
- RadoBuransky/sonar-scoverage-plugin

Error during SonarQube Scanner execution:

```
ERROR: You must install a plugin that supports the language 'scala'
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
ERROR: SonarQube scanner exited with non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: The current version of SonarQube is 6.5, and the current LTS is 5.6.6. You should seriously consider upgrading.

Comment: yeah but for the new versions I tried to figure out the plugins and it didn't help. So, by using version 5.4 I thought may be the plugins could work. I want to find a way for scala analysis of sbt code using sonarqube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their homepage (https://www.sonarqube.org/features/multi-languages/) Scala is not supported.

Comment: Yes, But I wanted to know if these third party plugins work effectively?

Comment: Does anyone know how to integrate sonarqube with jenkins with respect to Scala analysis ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a year old question. But I did integrate sonrqube-6.7.1 successfully in scala project for coverage as well as static code analysis.

1. For code coverage report using  scoverage

addSbtPlugin("org.scoverage" % "sbt-scoverage" % "1.5.1")

2. For code analysis using below plugin

addSbtPlugin("com.github.mwz" % "sbt-sonar" % "1.6.0")

3. install  sonarscala  and scoverage plugins  from Sonarqube marketplace
4. configure sonar-scanner on server and envirnment variable 
   SONAR_SCANNER_HOME = <>
5. sbt sonarScan -   this will publish reports to sonarqube

Answer (score 0):

Currently SonarQube supports Scala

https://www.sonarqube.org/features/multi-languages/scala/